# MySQL get 5 users and order by their count of views from pivot table

Tags: mysql

I have table users (id, name) and follow pivot table (follower_id, user_id). How can I get top 5 users with most views?
Edit:

### Users

id | name

1  | John
2 | Bob
3 | Max
4 | Greg

### Follow

follower_id | user_id
1 | 3
2 | 3
4 | 3
3 | 1
3 | 2
4 | 2

So the most followers has user by id 3 (Max), then 2 (Bob), then 1 (John). How can I write that query?

Comment: Can you make this a complete question by showing us some data?  Also, if you can paste any query you might have tried, that would be even better.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I edited my post, I don't have anything good to show. I tried with `SELECT id, name FROM users ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5` but this only orders them by id

Comment: As a hint, use `GROUP BY user_id` on the `Follow` table, along with `LIMIT 5`.  For future reference, questions on Stack Overflow which appear to be homework dumps usually get downvoted like this.  Show some effort for best results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT A.* FROM USERS A INNER JOIN
(SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) FOLLOW_COUNT  
  FROM FOLLOW GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY 
  COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 5) B 
ON A.user_id=B.user_id;
```